# How do I make an element hide until a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I am trying to get the Meet Some of Our Staff section to only show once the text "Meet Some of Our Staff" is clicked. I have used code that has gotten it to hide the section when "Meet Some of Our Staff" is clicked, but cannot figure out how to reverse it to where it is already hidden upon page load and then appears when "Meet Some of Our Staff" is clicked.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideshow(which){
if (!document.getElementById)
return
if (which.style.display="block")
which.style.display="none"
else
which.style.display="block"
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content3">
<div class="title2">
<h1><center><a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('staff'))">Meet Some
of Our Staff</a></center></h1>
</div>

<div id="staff">
<center>
<ul>

<a href="http://www.instituteforcreativelearners.org/" 
onclick="centeredPopup(this.href,'myWindow','500','300','yes');return false">
<li>
<img src="images/kami.jpg" alt="...">
<br />
<p><span class="stafftitle">Kami Barron</span> <br /> <span  
class="staffsubtitle">Director of Education</span></p>
</li>
</a>

</ul>
</center>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use CSS to set the display to none.

Comment: FYI: [`getElementById()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) is a **function** that requires 1 parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hamidlab/vs60c3ac/) - reformatted HTML/JS

Change

```
if (which.style.display="block")
```

to

```
if (which.style.display == "block")
```

if you are not setting `display:none` in CSS, then use this

```
if (!which.style.display || which.style.display == "block")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to hide the element when the page loads.

```
<div id="staff" style="display: none;">
```

That will hide the div until the user clicks on the link.

**Edit: Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve0pg14a/) for a working example using your code**

Answer (score 0):

On what you want to be hidden apply the CSS rule `display:none`. Then in Javascript,

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click",function(e)
{
    document.getElementById("staff").style.display="block";
    e.preventDefault()
});
```